# Компиляция php

Tags: php, компиляция

Вопрос можно ли скомпилировать php для работы на сервере (т.е. не интерпретировать через движок php, а скомпилировать и вызывать)?

Дело в том что нашел на хабре статью, сравнивающую twig со smarty и там была табличка с графой компиляция. Вот я не понял как они компилировали и имелось ли ввиду компиляция php скрипта или шаблона в быстрый php скрипт (как это делает смарти).

Также заинтересовал возможность компилирования, чтобы продавать под ключ сайты.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу, хотелось бы увидеть примеров парочку.

Comment: Про шаблонизаторы — имелось в виду второе.

Comment: понятно все со смарти) оставшаяся часть вопроса все еще интересна)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Имеется еще такая штука, как говорит википедия

> Zend Guard (ранее назывался Zend
> Encoder) — позволяет закодировать
> скрипт в байт-код, который потом можно
> использовать точно также как и
> обычный, за исключением возможности
> его отредактировать. Предназначено для
> защиты интересов и интеллектуальной
> собственности разработчика. Для работы
> таких скриптов обязательно нужен Zend
> Optimizer.
>
> Zend SafeGuard Suite — то же самое,
> что и Zend Encoder, только дополнен
> Zend License Manager, который
> позволяет создавать лицензии к
> кодируемым скриптам. Можно задать
> время (expire) и условия (привязка к
> IP, MAC, etc) работы. Удобно для
> Shareware-версий или демоверсий.
>
> Zend Optimizer — единственное
> приложение, распространяемое
> бесплатно. Являет собой серверный
> модуль для запуска закодированных с
> помощью Zend Encoder и Zend SafeGuard
> Suite скриптов, а также немного их
> ускоряющий (заявлено, что до 40 %).

Подробности о разработках Zend найдете [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Technologies). Цены, правда, запредельные, но как вариант я бы рассмотрел.

Comment: "Now supports PHP 5.5 and 5.6!
$600.00 yearly") sounds like a joke..
С офф. сайта: "Теперь есть поддержка PHP 5.5 и 5.6 - 600 баксов в год"
Звучит как стеб

Comment: @VasilySuricov, Вы про Zend Guard, так последняя версия 2015 года. Дорого? Скорее всего легаси код и старые клиенты, если верить вот этому посту https://www.zend.com/blog/zend-guard-and-php-7

Answer (score 4):

Например - http://www.phpcompiler.org/

со странички

phc for PHP programmers (See Manual):

- Compile PHP source into an (optimized) executable (supports entire PHP standard library).
- Compile a web application into an (optimized) extension (supports entire PHP standard library).
- Pretty-print PHP code.
- Obfuscate PHP code (--obfuscate flag - experimental).
- Combine many php scripts into a single file (--include flag - experimental).
- Optimize PHP code using classical compiler optimizations (in the dataflow branch - very experimental).

  - компиляция php в (оптимизированный) исполняемый файл (с полной поддержкой стандартных библитек php)
  - компиляция web-приложения в (оптимизированное) расширение (с полной поддержкой стандартных библитек php)
  - обфускация PHP кода (изменение кода таким образом, чтобы затруднить его анализ и понимание) (экспериментальная версия)
  - комбинирование нескольких php скриптов в один файл
  - оптимизация php скриптов с использованием классических методов оптимизации (экспериментальная версия)

Answer (score 4):

В Facebook компилируют PHP в C++, используя [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/). Вроде как, это наиболее шустрое, из имеющихся на данное время решений. Правда, не поддерживаются некоторые конструкции, например, `eval()`.

По сравнению с PHP+Apache (mod_php), по заявлениям Facebook, экономится около 50% процессорного времени при отдаче веб-интерфейса, и около 30% при отдаче API.

Еще был (нынче, можно сказать, [помер от нехватки интереса](http://roadsend-php.blogspot.com/2010/08/current-status.html)) [проект Raven](http://code.roadsend.com/rphp) от Roadsend, который компилировал в байт-код LLVM, со всеми вытекающими плюсами оной (переносимость между платформами/архитектурами, JIT и т.д.)

Comment: по поводу хип хопа, как оно работает потом? в смысле подключается как то к веб серверу?

Comment: Судя по документации — встроенный HTTP-сервер при запуске с `-m server` (или `-m daemon`), порт указывается по опции `-p`. Про другие режимы (CGI, FastCGI?) не знаю — надо брать и проверять.

Answer (score 0):

Компиляция это не про php - Это интерпретируемый язык.
Его код на сервере как раз и интерпретируется.

twig со smarty Сравнивали  тк они действительно нужнаются в компиляции (и скорость их обработки разная).

И php кстате тоже является шаблонизатором, причем нативным. smfrty и еже с ними призваны углубить (усугубить)  принцип MVC, что бы при выводе html кода не возникало соблазна модифицировать данные

Comment: про шаблоны исчерпывающе, но хотелось бы про компиляцию подробнее

Comment: ды нету в php компиляции, оптимизация да, но не компиляция. Вопросы компиляции тут относятся к шаблонизаторам